# How to deploy local project to Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, django, amazon-s3

I have a small webapp written in Python/Django which works fine on my local machine. I've been tinkering and setting up my server on the free tier of Amazon EC2 by following online tutorials. However, the tutorials I have found so far shows you how to setup your instance and stops there.

So my question is, how do I get my local webapp onto my Amazon instance?

FYI, I'm a sys admin/web dev. noob.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simpler, non-automated method, you just need a way to copy your files from your local machine to the web server directory on your EC2 instance.  Try an SCP client such as [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for Windows or [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) for Mac - you can set both tools up to use the SSH key for your EC2 instance.

Your EC2 image should already have Apache HTTPD on it so that you can deploy your Django app; looks like you have that covered since you've got it running locally, but post back here if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating using a combo of tools to do something pretty similar.  Fabric is killer for this and I have been using http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2009/11/automated-deployments-with-puppet-and.html as a base guide.

boto seems like it would be good to use for scripting AWS setups, but I have not yet dived into it.  http://groups.google.com/group/pinoy-python-users/browse_thread/thread/de264059d2ba7bb1

Once I have an environment set up I am setting it up to pull my code from my Github repo.  I think I'll set up github to push out changes as a post-commit hook, but we'll see.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220278/how-to-use-github-and-ec2-together-to-deploy-a-python-application

This is an interesting question and i can't wait to see everyone else's answers.

Comment: It's amazingly mind boggling for a newbie.

Comment: My answer may have been overkill.  In the beginning, I just uploaded my files with scp, but now I'm managing multiple instances and setting them all up by hand is time consuming.  The choices are many, but it is more important to get mucking around with these, until you find a way that works for you.